# get icon from shortcut or shortcut target (exe) and sticon for button in pyqt5 python

Tags: python, icons

This is my first program. The application displays a list of buttons corresponding to software, taken from the "menu" folder previously defined. However, I don't know how to get the icon of the shortcut or the shortcut target (.exe) in the menu folder to set the icon for the QPushButton. I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ....
                # Set the path to the menu folder
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.apps_folder = os.path.join(current_dir, "menu")
        .......

    def create_app_buttons(self):
        app_names = os.listdir(self.apps_folder)
        for app_name in app_names:
            if app_name.endswith(".lnk"):
                button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
                button.setMinimumSize(75, 75)
                button.setToolTip(app_name[:-4])
                button.setText(app_name[:-4])
                button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
                button.clicked.connect(self.run_app)
                self.app_buttons.append(button)
```

i tried qicon,qpixmap but there seems to be a mistake somewhere